# Отслеживание CSS переменных через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

У меня есть анимация в CSS, которая изменяет CSS переменные.

Я бы хотел через JavaScript отслеживать изменения `CSS переменных` и в зависимости от значения делать какие-то действия(можно сделать анимацию чисто на JS, но мне интересно так). Если у кого-то есть какие-то мысли, подскажите

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@property --x {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

@property --y {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

@property --r {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

@property --g {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

@property --b {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(var(--r), var(--g), var(--b));
  animation: ballAnimate 2s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

.ball {
  --size: 10vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background-color: rgb(var(--r), var(--g), var(--b));
  filter: invert(100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1vmin), calc(var(--y) * 1vmin));
  animation: ballAnimate 2s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes ballAnimate {
  0% {
    --x: 0;
    --y: 0;
  }
  25% {
    --y: 20;
    
    --r: 100;
    --g: 100;
    --b: 30;
  }
  50% {
    --x: 30;
  }
  75% {
    --y: 50;
    
    --r: 255;
    --g: 0;
    --b: 255;
  }
  100% {
    --x: 200;
    --y: 80;
    
    --r: 0;
    --g: 255;
    --b: 250;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

«Отслеживать», вероятно, через [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), вызывается примерно 60 раз в секунду.

```js
(function loop() {
  let style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
  
  let x = style.getPropertyValue('--x');
  let y = style.getPropertyValue('--y');
  
  console.clear();
  console.log('x:', x, '| y:', y);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@property --x {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

@property --y {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

@property --r {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

@property --g {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

@property --b {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<number>';
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(var(--r), var(--g), var(--b));
  animation: ballAnimate 2s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

.ball {
  --size: 10vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background-color: rgb(var(--r), var(--g), var(--b));
  filter: invert(100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1vmin), calc(var(--y) * 1vmin));
  animation: ballAnimate 2s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes ballAnimate {
  0% {
    --x: 0;
    --y: 0;
  }
  25% {
    --y: 20;
    
    --r: 100;
    --g: 100;
    --b: 30;
  }
  50% {
    --x: 30;
  }
  75% {
    --y: 50;
    
    --r: 255;
    --g: 0;
    --b: 255;
  }
  100% {
    --x: 200;
    --y: 80;
    
    --r: 0;
    --g: 255;
    --b: 250;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: о, классно! Что-то не додумался